# OS X network accounts - disable login but still allow Connect To Server?

Tags: login, mac-osx-server, network-share

I have some network user accounts on an OS X 10.5 Leopard server.

Is it possible to disable login at the login window, but still allow them to connect to their home account via Finder and Connect To Server?

If I untick 'access account' in the Workgroup Manager, the user can no longer login nor connect to server, so that's a bit too harsh.

Answer (score 2):

I'm certain this works in 10.6, and I'm pretty sure it was the same way in 10.5.    For the user to have access to any services, you need to leave their account enabled in Workgroup Manager.    Login is controlled by the Server Admin app for each device by restricting who can log in and who cannot.    By default, all registered accounts can log in on all machines which enable login.   However, you can restrict this service by changing the Access settings for the server.

1. Connect to the server in question using the Server Admin
2. Choose the Access tab with the server itself (not a specific service) selected in the source list at the left
3. Under Services, choose "For Selected Services Below" (allowing you to differentiate on the basis of service)
4. Now choose "Login Window" from the left list and "Allow only users and groups below" from the right side
5. Make sure you add groups or users to the list in order to enable login for those users.

Comment: 5.1: Make sure you add *yourself* to the list.

Comment: While that works, I want to *disable* specific users, the Access tab in Server Admin is only a whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

Found it - Workgroup Manager. I already have a computer group for all the client machines. The Login->Access preferences allow me to set up an ACL to allow all network users, but deny specific users.